# RSpec: testing sidekiq worker for race condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, rspec, sidekiq

Sometimes I have situation when the same worker running twice - when user sending requests fast, one by one. I added condition: if worker was already started and inside worker's `payload` is class `Importer` - don't allow to start queue second time.

Now I need to make a spec for it. I think, that to call smth like this is not a good way:

```
before { 2.times { Importer.perform } }
```

What is the best way to test worker for such race condition? (generally: in which way to test Sidekiq worker when you need to run same query twice or more)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there are was no answers.

I decided just to stub it. Inside Import class I have `Sidekiq::Workers.new`, so inside spec I placed `let(:sidekiq_workers)` block with all worker's parameters, like `queue`, `payload`, `args` and so on.

Then inside `it` block I'm calling method, that checking if such query already exists. This test passes and returns "true". I have another `it` block without stubbed sidekiq workers and test passes with "false".

Comment: because you are testing your app, and not sidekiq, it's good practice to use stubbing. you assume sidekiq works fine, so the job of the class you are testing ends when the job has been properly enqueued to sidekiq. you don't need to test any more.